# How to handle multiple async operations using promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, callback

I have some code with 2 functions. `taskA` requires some value and gets that value via a callback that returns the value inside a promise. It then returns the result of doing something with that value via a second callback. `taskB` provides the value via a callback that is also passed as a parameter, but this callback is synchronous.

How can I get the value from `taskB` and pass it to `taskA`, and get the result to pass it back to `taskB`? I can modify `taskA`, but `taskB` must provide its value and obtain a result via a synchronous callback.

```
async function taskA(requestValue: () => Promise<Value>, provideResult: (result: Result) => void) {
  while(someCondition) {
    let value: Value = await requestValue();
    let result: Result = processValue(value);
    provideResult(result);
  }
}

function taskB(valueCallback: (value: Value) => Result) {
  let state: State = someState;
  ...
  let handleEvent = (event) => {
    let result: Result = valueCallback(convertToValue(event));
    state = updateState(result);
  }
}
```

Here's a sequence diagram of the behaviour I want to enable:
[image: sequence diagram]

Comment: I'm not understanding your question perfectly, but can't you just call `taskA()` in `taskB()`?

Comment: `taskA` doesn't make much sense. Surely `await requestValue();` should be returning the result that the callback uses: `const result = await requestValue();`. At the moment you're calling the callback with a value that it's passing in already passing in as an argument, which seems redundant. Note also: `Result` is not the same as `result`.

Comment: @code `taskB` is in a library whose source code I do not want to modify.

Comment: @Andy edited for clarity. Result is a type, and result is a variable of type Result.

Comment: Is `taskA` meant to call `provideResult` multiple times? If not, don't accept a callback at all, `return` the result!

Comment: @Bergi It's meant to request a value multiple times, and for each value request, it provides the result of that value once.

Comment: And what do you expect `handleEvent` (in `taskB`) to do with *multiple* values? Apart from not being able to handle asynchronous results, it also doesn't appear to be capable of handling multiple results.

Comment: @Bergi I see what you mean, but what I want is for taskB to wait for an event to generate a new value. i.e. for the `requestValue` promise to resolve only when there is a value available. Give me a few minutes to draw a diagram and update the question

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use `taskA` in `valueCallback`, or `taskB` in `requestValue`?

Comment: @Bergi I am trying to write a controller that handles the data flow between both. Updated the question with a diagram for clarity

Comment: This is something that asynchronous iterators might be able to do. Is the "handle result" step necessarily within `taskB` (I presume `updateState`)? Also it seems that `taskB` should end (stop receiving events) once the loop condition is met, which the current implementation also doesn't account for. You really will need to rewrite both of them.

Comment: Task B does have an API for updating the state, so I can potentially do that inside the controller. My main concern with that is that the Task B state may be inconsistent with Task A until the update is done.

I might also try rewriting Task A to process the value synchronously - it shouldn't take too long and that will allow me to use the existing sync function for Task B.